# Sane filenames with wget

Tags: wget

I'm downloading a list of files from urls that contain addtional information past the filenames with wget. This results in filenames like:

pythonbook.pdf@y=11&x=123

All I really want is the pythonbook.pdf part. My file list is basically a list of URLs like:

https://dl.domain.com/pythonbook.pdf@y=11&x=123

How can I not have the unnecessary part of the filename?

Comment: if a list of urls has the same common part `pythonbook.pdf`, then that parameter string is the only thing that distinguishes those filenames. In such case you need to elaborate the final naming convention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably easiest to iterate over the whole list in this case (as `wget` doesn't seem to have support for the dynamic creation of output file names):

```
while read url; do
    t=${url##*/}  # removes protocol and hostname
    pdf=${t%@*}   # removes part from @ onwards
    wget -O "$pdf" "$url"
done < LIST-OF-URLs
```

`url` is the URL read from the list of URLs in the file, `pdf` is just the file name part of it.

---

In case the names are non-unique you can add a number to the file name, e.g. like this (assuming all files are PDFs):

```
i=0
while read url; do
    t=${url##*/}      # removes protocol and hostname
    pdf=${t%.pdf@*}   # removes part from .pdf@ onwards
    wget -O "$pdf-$i.pdf" "$url"
    ((i++))
done < LIST-OF-URLs
```

or (if the files have different suffixes)

```
i=0
while read url; do
    t=${pdf##*/}    # removes protocol and hostname
    pdf=${t%@*}     # removes part from @ onwards
    wget -O "$i-$pdf" "$url"
    ((i++))
done < LIST-OF-URLs
```

Comment: So the $pdf part is the new file name?

Comment: @Columbia_Bob uups, naming was a bit confusing, hope it's better now.